# hide div in web browser control using win forms c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms

Using win forms with a web browser control displaying an external URL. Trying to hide a `<div>` when displaying the page in the web browser control.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("menu").Style = "display:none";
    }
```

The id of the `<div>` is `menu`, when I navigate to the page with the div visual studio throws the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("menu").Style = "display:none"; - error is for all of that.

Comment: yes, but something within this line is null. It can be `webBrowser1`, `webBrowser1.Document`, `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("menu")` and so on. Find the null, and you'll find a good tip to solve the issue

Comment: it appears the <div> is inside an <iframe>, that is why it is getting a null value for the <div>. Any way to force the <iframe> to show its content's on load so that I can hide the <div>?

Comment: I think that the Iframe's content is considered as a document itself. In the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` handler, can you check the url of the retrieved document ? If not, you should first find the IFrame using document.getElementById, then, find the div within the Iframe

Comment: How would I `getElementById` for the `IFrame` then search for another element and hide it? I tested "display:none" on the `IFrame` and it does it to all the `<div>` within the `IFrame`. Not sure how to target and hide a single `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

The DocumentCompleted gets fired for each frame that is nested in the page.
What you can try to do:

```
if(e.Url == YOUR URL){
     HtmlElement menu = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("menu");
     if(menu != null){
           menu.Style = "display:none";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used WebBrowser in C# yet, but it seems that the Style is similar to CSS, so maybe try using **display:none** instead of *visibility:hidden*. Hope that helps...